# woocommerce list of available city (is it possible?)

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to create, in addition to the state and country arrays, a list for cities.

I have seen everywhere but I can not quite understand how and if it is possible to extract it.

I read of this: [get_city();](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Legacy_Customer.html#219-225) but it leads to the billing data already entered by the user. I need a possible list of the cities already present.

I tried to follow the logic with which I extracted the rest

```
$countries = WC()->countries;
$countries_array = WC()->countries->get_allowed_countries();
$country_states_array = WC()->countries->get_allowed_country_states();


foreach($countries_array as $k => $v)
{
    echo '<option value="'.$k.'">'.$v.'</option>';  
}


echo '<div class="space[15]"><hr /></div>';


foreach ($country_states_array as $item)
{
    echo "<div style='border: 1px solid blue;'>";

    foreach ($item as $v)
    {
        echo " ".$v;
    }

    echo "</div>";
}

echo '<div class="space[15]"><hr /></div>';



//NOT WORKING.... ok....
$country_city = WC()->countries->get_allowed_city(); //does not exist
foreach ($country_city as $c)
{
    echo "<div style='border: 1px solid red;'>";

        echo " ".$c;

    echo "</div>";
}
```

but it does not work.

does this list of cities exist or am I imagining it?

Comment: i believe you need to use external API to get list of cities as WooCommerce have only list of counties

Comment: There is no list of cities in Woocommerce by default and no related class to handle them (like `WC_Countries` for the countries and states)… You should search if there is no related plugins (even wordpress plugins) or use an external API as *kashalo* suggest.

Comment: ah ... so there is not a list of cities. (desperation hahahahaha)